# Extracting 2 strings from 2 listviews in adroidstudio

Tags: android

I have 2 listviews in 1 activity (1 on the left 1 on the right of screen). I want 2 strings extracted from both list views and use them else where in the code (either in the same activity but different class or different activity). I have tried assigning clicked items to a public variable and then posting them on a text view bit I see nothing. Please help or suggest another better way. Here is a sample of my code:

```
public class Tabs extends Activity {    
String CF =""; //Convert To
String CT =""; //Convert From
populateListView(); //function that populates my listview (not shown here)

ListView listMassFrom = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewMassFrom);
ListView listMassTo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewMassTo);

listMassFrom.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {

            String convFrom = ((TextView) viewClicked).getText().toString();
            CF = convFrom;
        }
    });



listMassTo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {

            String convTo = ((TextView) viewClicked).getText().toString();
            CT = convTo;
        }
    });


//Test to see if the two string were extracted from the onItemClick method:
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test1);
    t1.setText(CT);

    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test2);
    t2.setText(CF);
   }
}
```

Comment: Call `t1.setText(CT);`  and `t.setText(CF);` inside `onItemClick` method

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to be able to use CT and CF strings outside of onItemClick. The set.Text is just there to test whether the value has been extracted from onItemClick or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should access items via adapters using the parameter `position`.

Supposing your adapter contains `Strings` (Otherwise adapt it to your data model):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
    CF = <listMassFrom_adapter>.getItem(position);
}
```

---

EDIT:

Example tested and working. You can see a toast when items are selected.

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.testbutton.R;

public class Tabs extends Activity {
    final static String[] MassUnits = { "kg", "g", "mg", "lb", "lbm", "slug" };
    String CF = ""; // Convert To
    String CT = ""; // Convert From
    ListView listMassFrom, listMassTo;
    ListAdapter adapterFrom, adapterTo;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

        // Find views
        listMassFrom = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvFrom);
        listMassTo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTo);

        // Create list of items
        adapterFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MassUnits);
        listMassFrom.setAdapter(adapterFrom);

        adapterTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MassUnits);
        listMassTo.setAdapter(adapterTo);

        listMassFrom
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View viewClicked, int position, long id) {

                    String convFrom = (String) adapterFrom
                            .getItem(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "From: " + convFrom, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        listMassTo
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View viewClicked, int position, long id) {

                    String convTo = (String) adapterTo.getItem(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "To: " + convTo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Layout `tabs.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvFrom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvTo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I think it is better to use spinners, but you can adapt the code if that's the case.

Comment: It can not resolve listMassFrom_adapter and getItem. They both appear in red. I believe adapter contains string.

Comment: Here is populateListView():

Comment: private void populateListView() {
        //  Create list of itmes
        String[] MassUnits = {"kg","g","mg","lb","lbm","slug"};

        //  Build Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.unit_items, MassUnits);
        ListView listMassFrom = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewMassFrom);
        listMassFrom.setAdapter(adapter);
}

Comment: Store the `adapter` as a class member, so you can invoke its methods from onItemClick. In fact, you should have two adapters, one for each list, but I'm focusing in one. You can replicate the behaviour for the other once it's working.

Comment: I am just a beginner. It is the first time I use adapters and listviews. I have no idea how to store adapter as a class member. Perhaps you can show me?

Comment: The same as `CF` and `CT`. They are member variables, so you can use them in the whole scope of your class 'Tabs'. Your adapter is a local variable, so its scope is just the method where it is declared. Therefore you can't use them in the `onClick` events that is just what you need.

Comment: I tried making my adapter as a class member by declaring it right after set setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

Comment: Seems to be the same issue: It can not resolve listMassFrom_adapter and getItem. They both appear in red. I believe adapter contains string.

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

        //  Create list of itmes
        String[] MassUnits = {"kg","g","mg","lb","lbm","slug"};
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.unit_items, MassUnits);

        ListView listMassFrom = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewMassFrom);
        listMassFrom.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: You move a local variable from one method to another. I just edited my answer with an example based on your code. It's tested and working, so use that as a preliminar version and continue developing your app with that. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Juanjo, but when I try assigning CF to convFrom (CF=convFrom) inside listMassFrom.setOnItemClickListener(), and then try to view CF outside of it. I see nothing in text view (as it was originally assigned "").

Comment: Are you setting text? `yourtextview.setText(convFrom)` inside onClick. Update your question with your current code.